# How to make fsockopen to ignore certificates when using tls

Tags: php, ssl

In PHP7.0, when using fsockopen to connect to open a https connection (hosted in same
host), using a host name like `tls://foo.localhost`, I am getting an error that
looks like

```
fsockopen(): Peer certificate CN="bar" did not match expected CN="foo.localhost"
```

Connection is not opened.

Same code worked in PHP 5.5 (that is less strict checking vertificates).  I do
not really care about verifying certificates (this code runs in a unit test and
integration suite, connecting only to localhost).  Tests need to be run against
http and https, though.

I know how to disable those checks when using `file_get_contents`.

How can I disable the peer certificate verification when using fsockopen?

Comment: Does the `verify_peer` [context option](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) affect this?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I don't know how to pass a context to `fsockopen`

Comment: Never worked with sockets, I presume [stream_context_set_default()](http://php.net/) should work. If it doesn't, try the function suggested in [fsockopen()](http://php.net/fsockopen) manual page: "The function [stream_socket_client()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) is similar but provides a richer set of options, including non-blocking connection and the ability to provide a stream context. "

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, context_set_default does not work with `fsockopen`.  Most likely `stream_socket_client` is the way to go (I was reluctant because the `fsockopen` it is at the core of the not-very-modern test library I need to use).  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`fsockopen` don't provide method to ignore peer certificate errors.

You have to use [`stream_socket_client`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) with [`context`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php). Available ssl/tls context options are available [here](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php).

Example of opening socket without peer verification

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false
    ]
]);

$hostname = "tls://foo.localhost:8123";
$socket = stream_socket_client($hostname, $errno, $errstr, ini_get("default_socket_timeout"), STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

Comment: Correct and also option **'verify_peer_name' => false** might be necessary in case of some odd DEV hostname.

Comment: how to specify the port using stream_socket_client instead of fsockopen?

Comment: @ShadiNamrouti you can include port in $hostname, e.g. `$hostname = "tls://foo.localhost:8123";`